# LDAP authentication with django REST

Tags: python, django, ldap, django-rest-framework

Currently I have basic authorization on for visting the Django REST Api backend and I can use the `username  / passowrd` which was created via `shell`

I don't have login page for that I am using all that is built in.

Now i want to authenticate the username /password from LDAP from my Active Directory.

Is there any way that I don't need to create Login page for that and I can enter the username / password on same place and my user authenticates with Active Directory.

Do I need to create some manual logic of getting username password and then postig it, I was thinking if I can get it without doing that stuff like basic authentication which django already provides

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a package called [django-auth-ldap](https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/). 
It comes with a django authentification backend. 
Just add `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend` to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

You probably have to define a few more settings like you ldap host. But the documentation is quite good.

Then you can use your normal authentication views and `django` "decide" which method to use. There is more information in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends)

Comment: If i use `AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN` and `AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD` and other settings in setiings.py file . DO i need to do anything else in view or all i need is settings file and i can log in with Ad username , password

Comment: If you configure the settings right, you don't have to change anything in your views

Comment: Another popular package for this is [`django-python3-ldap`](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap).

Comment: Can we make ldaps authentication with ssl