# Django authentication with basic auth with LDAP support and no User model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ldap

This is my first Django project so please bear with me. I am creating a pure DRF project.

My requirement is that the user will call the REST APIs while sending the user creds in basic auth format which I need to validate against a LDAP server.

Also, each API with have the credentials sent and so I do not need to store the credentials at my end (in the default USER model)

I was aiming to use :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    )
} and 
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
}
```

to be able to read the basic auth creds and then hoping to hook in:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
]
```

to authenticate the user at LDAP server.

questions:

-- is there any better approach ?

-- since I am only passing on the credentials to LDAP server to know if the creds are valid, I do not need the USER table in the database. I need it only for object modeling. How can I acheive this? would a Proxy model help? Can we have an abstract model as the AUTH_USER_MODEL? 
or using a remote user authentication backend a better option?

Comment: is `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend` is coming from specific package or it is your custom Backend?

Comment: @AhmedHosny: it is : https://github.com/django-auth-ldap/django-auth-ldap

Comment: so do you mean about binding the user, is to use this setting `AUTH_LDAP_BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER ` mentioned here https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#std:setting-AUTH_LDAP_BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER ?

Comment: No, I mean whenever we use the contrib.auth there is a user model associated with it. This model is mapped to the database table. I do not need this database table. I want that whatevr basic auth info i get in DRF, I am able to pass that onto the LDAP lib.

Answer (score 0):

To make a short answer, Yes you can make a class that replaces the User model, Like this:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, authenticated=False, email=None):
        self.is_authenticated = authenticated
        self.email = email
```

The real question is how to let your Authentication middleware returns this in your `request.user`. There are multiple ways (I've never used `django-auth-ldap` so may be I'm not writing the best practice for it.):

**One solution could be:**

is to inherit from this class `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend` https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend

class CustomLDAP(LDAPBackend)
    def get_user_model(self):
        # return your custom user
```

and then you need to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` to

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'path.to.CustomLDAP',
]
```

I'm not sure if you want this `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`
if you are working with `django-auth-ldap`. May be this [LDAP authentication with django REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550169/ldap-authentication-with-django-rest)
also help

**READ THIS FIRST**

I think also here https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users.html they explain it well. So, may be the solution lies in package itself